# SGD not working on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I've been trying to use factorization machine (http://www.algo.uni-konstanz.de/members/rendle/pdf/Rendle2010FM.pdf) on a dataset for a classification problem (ERROR VS NO ERROR), using stochastic gradient descent as a learning method. 
I'm trying to use it for a very sparse matrix (1000 columns, 1-0 only and around 90% of the entry values are 0) as recommanded.

Thing is it doesn't really work : when I try to apply my code to a testing_set, V and w are almost constant during the process. There's no variation or convergence or whatsoever. 
The result is that in the end, I get a prediction data where there's absolutely no error detected.
My first guess was that maybe that's because my data is very unbalanced (10% errors), so I've changed my training set according to that and I've got now a training set with 14 000 rows where 7000 are errors. Still doesn't change a thing !

I've tried all day long to see where I got it wrong but I can't seem to find it. I tried both 'ypred' and 'grad_hinge' on very specific values for V,w, did the math on a paper and they seem to both work just fine.
SDG only uses those two functions and it seems to me that the implementation is good comparing to what SDG is in theory (http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf, page 7).

Here is my code :

```
def ypred(V,w,x):
j=0
x2=[nb*nb for nb in x]
for f in range (V.shape[1]):
    v2=[nb*nb for nb in V[:,f]]
    j+=np.dot(x,V[:,f])**2-np.dot(x2,v2)
return w[0]+np.dot(w[1:],x)+0.5*j
```

This first one is the y_hat introduced in Rendle's article (p2 and 3). I tested that with

```
Vtest=np.array([[0.5,3,4],[5,1,0],[8,1,2],[9,-4,5]])
wtest=np.array([0.5,0.3,2,4,0.8])
xtest=np.array([1,4,6,2])
y_main=0.5+(0.3+8+24+1.6)+0.5*((0.5+20+48+18)**2-(0.25+400+1728+324)+(3+4+6-8)**2-(9+16+36+64)+26**2-(16+144+60))
ypred(Vtest,wtest,xtest)
```

I get **y_pred=2914.4**, which is the good result.

```
def grad_hinge(V,w,x,y):
Jv=np.zeros(V.shape)
Jw=np.zeros(len(w))
y_hat=ypred(V,w,x)
c=y*y_hat
Jw[0]= 0 if c > 1 else -y
for i in range (1,len(w)):
    Jw[i]= 0 if  c > 1 else -y*x[i-1]
for i in range (V.shape[0]):
    for k in range (V.shape[1]):
        Jv[i,k]=0 if c > 1 else -y*(x[i]*np.dot(V[:,k],x)-V[i,k]*(x[i]**2))
return Jw,Jv
```

grad_hinge is for hinge loss gradient. There are two class of parameters (w_i and v_{i,j}) and that's why I introduce Jw and Jv. Tested with :

```
Vtest=np.array([[0.5,3],[5,1],[-2,1],[1,-4]])
wtest=np.array([0.5,0.3,2,4,0.8])
xtest=np.array([1,0,0,1])
y=1
print(ypred(Vtest,wtest,xtest))
print(grad_hinge(Vtest,wtest,xtest,y))
```

It returns **w=[-1, -1, 0, 0,-1]** and **V=[[-1,4],[0,0],[0,0],[-0.5,-3]]**, which is the expected result.

```
def SDG(V,w,X,Y,a,c,niter):
delta1, delta2, epoch = [100],[100], 0
while ((norm(delta1, np.inf) >c or norm(delta2, np.inf)>c) and epoch < niter) :
    for i in range (X.shape[0]):
        print(i*100/X.shape[0])
        Jw,Jv=grad_hinge(V,w,X[i],Y[i])
        w1=np.array([w[j]-a*Jw[j] for j in range(len(w))])
        V1=np.zeros(V.shape)
        for i in range (V.shape[0]):
            V1[i]=[V[i,k] - a*Jv[i,k] for k in range (V.shape[1])]
    delta1=w1-w
    delta2=V1-V
    w,V=w1,V1
    epoch+=1
print(epoch)
return w,V
```

Here I try to implement SGD as described in Andrew Ng's course (link up there).

Can someone tell me where in my code I may have flaws ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "It doesn't work good" and "the results are horrible" are not problem specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your advices Prune. I tried to do as you told me. I edited my message and added further description of my problem and gave my test.